# laravel 5.3 hosting issue - not loading css

Tags: php, html, laravel-5, hosting

I'm trying to make my laravel app live on godaddy, I moved the public folder content to the root public_html folder and the app is up and running, here is the [link](http://financialconsaltant.com/), css file and images are not loading. why is that?

my link to css file is gives the write path when I use `inspect element` on browser. but not really working.

here the code to link to css file:

```
<link href="{{ URL::asset('css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

I also tried:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

and:

```
<link href="{{ HTML::style('css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

none is working for me on hosting but working fine on localhost

my images code to link images:

```
{{ URL::asset('images/logo.png')}}
```

Comment: did u put `css` and `image` folder in `public` folder ?

Comment: yes, not working too

Comment: where did u put your index.php file ?

Comment: at the hosting 'public_html' folder

Comment: try adding `{{ asset('public/css/style.css')}}`

Comment: also not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem that on hosting you should type the full path from public_html folder on hosting

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not hosting issue, your style.css not exists in css folder and images in images folder. Upload these files.
If you see in console, you will find a 404 not found error.

```
style.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
logo.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
slide1.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
slide2.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
financial.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
slide3.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/favicon.ico:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
style.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a another way to deal missing js and css file if file are present but show 404 error [Laravel link href invalid path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66094297/laravel-link-href-invalid-path/66097338#66097338)

Comment: this should be in comment box or mark as duplicate since this not provides an answer to question

Comment: this is an answer to the question. The issue was not absence of file its related to missing  file path at shared hosting.