# Laravel link href invalid path

Tags: css, laravel, url-rewriting

I have website in Laravel.
In `.env` file I set:

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:8082/mydomain/public
```

I use XAMPP on Windows. My `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

When I load main website in the browser I have errors like that:

```
 http://localhost:8082/js/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

It cannot load any js or css beacuse the correct path should be:

```
 http://localhost:8082/mydomain/public/js/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

In file in `php` link looks like :

```
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
@yield('script')
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the ```.htaccess``` file you have referenced in the root of your project? Try setting your ```APP_URL``` to just ```http://localhost:8082```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try this code put it in your app/Helpers/helper.php

function asset($path, $secure = null){
    return app('url')->asset("public/" . $path, $secure);
}

and access resource like eg

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('FOLDER_NAME/css/FILENAEM_EXTENSION') }}">
```